# Reverse unsigned to signed conversion in Java

Tags: java, c++

Using C++, an int gets converted from "signed" to "unsigned".

Can I convert this "unsigned" int back to "signed" using Java.

> Signed value (-3) converted in to unsigned (65533) using C++.
>
> How can i convert unsigned (65533) value back to signed (-3) using Java

Thanks in advance.

Prav

Comment: What do you want to achieve by that?

Comment: 65533 is an acceptable signed int value in Java

Comment: I need the actual signed value back. And in my interface I am using JAVA language.

Comment: Why do you "convert" (that is, reinterprete) the integers in the first place? Signed integer overflow is not even defined behaviour...

Comment: You pretty much have to do that before you move the data into Java, because Java doesn't have an unsigned types. Since you can't have `unsigned (65533)` in the first place, converting it to something else can't really arise.

Comment: yes you are correct, 65533 is acceptable in JAVA, but i need the actual value (signed value) back.

Comment: @praveen: 65533 *is* a signed value... Do you mean how to get the corresponding negative value with the same 16-bit binary representation on x86?

Comment: Yes Niklas, I want negative value back.

Comment: Try `value - 0x10000`. Note that this is not portable at all (but then again, the integer overflow is neither).

Comment: can you send some example code

Comment: @praveen: I just did. You have to replace `value` by `65533`, obviously.

Comment: By the way, the problem is *very likely* to be your C++ program or the way you interface with it. You should fix the cause, not the symptom.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9378/discussion-between-praveen-and-niklas-b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you have some value like

```
int value = 65533;
```

and you want it to be treated as a signed 16-bit integer, for which the solution is really, really simple:

```
short signed = (short) value; // -3
```

Comment: Uh, yes.  That's really the only source of unsigned values I can imagine in Java, since all primitive types are always signed.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the question. He has an external C++ program which breaks a 16-bit value for him. Now he wants to reinterpret a 16-bit unsigned integer as a signed integer (of course both are represented in Java as `int`s).

Comment: How did he get that 16-bit unsigned integer as a signed integer?

Comment: Louis. How can i get signed 32 bit integer back?

Comment: @praveen: You can't store the unsigned representation of a 32-bit negative value in a Java `int`, so the question doesn't make a lot of sense. The answer remains the same, though: Fix the type mismatches in your C/Java bridge.

Comment: Ok, But i can use JAVA long then.

Comment: If you want to copy it to an `int` or `long`, just cast it back up; upcasts won't change the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
if (a > 32767) a -= 65536;
```

Comment: `0x7fff` and `0x10000` would look a bit less random.

Answer (score 0):

An int in C++ is usually 32bit, however, you are talking of 65533 as -3 so your int has 16 bits. Most people will consider 16bit int as short (int)

An int/Integer in Java is ALWAYS 32 bit.

When you want to convert the signed short int: -3 to unsigned short int you get just 65533. This is regarding the bits a nop.

In Java just do

```
 int i = 65533; // or other values from unsigned short int

 if (i >= (1<<15) {
    i -= 1 << 16;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You used C++ to interpret a signed integer and represent it as an unsigned 2 byte integer.

The way back only works on the assumption that the representation is a 2 byte integer, by or-ing back the sign-extended bits (caveat, this is untested) the following should work:

```
int number = 65533;

// check sign bit for 2-byte integer, add in sign bits for 4 byte integer if set 
int signedNumber = (0 == (number & 0x8000)) ? number : (number | 0xFFFF0000);
```